# Migrate specific data from OnPrem (SQL DB ) to Azure (SQL DB)

Tags: c#, .net, azure

Is anyone know how to migrate data for specific clients from OnPrem SQL DB to Azure DB? I am thinking of provisioning service using c# code which takes time to develop. Is there any other way other than mentioned solution. Please take note that I am not planning to move all the data from OnPrem to Azure, since the one to be migrated are those clients upgraded their license to use the application hosted in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **BACPAC** to migrate our on-prem sql database to Azure Sql database.

- To do that we have some **Prerequisites** as follows

. **Storage account**.

. **Container**

. **Azure sql database & Local SQL database**

In order to achive that connect your database using SSMS to azure SQL server by copied the URL after creation of Azure sql database:

[image]

[image]

- After connecting , Goto the database which you want to migrate . By right click on the database click the followings as below:

[image]

Click on next and select browse and create a local folder and save it as BACPAC. file

[image]

[image]

[image]

After creation of file click on next :
[image]

[image]

- Once done Go to your storage > Container> Create container

[image]

Inside container > Upload> select file

[image]

Once upload your file that we have created earlier as above , Go to your SQL Server and

[image]

Make sure you have selected the correct storage account where we have upload the files earlier inside containers. And add your login details:
[image]

Here is successfully migrated  specified files to Azure SQL server.

[image]

Please refer this blog for more information:
[BLOG| Migrate an on-premises SQL Server database to an Azure SQL database](https://www.sqlshack.com/migrate-an-on-premises-sql-server-database-to-the-azure-sql-database/)